# How align logo with links?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a SVG logo in the css correctly with the links that are being collected through MYSQL. I am unable to style the links so they align centrally with the SVG. I have tried the usual tricks of adding vertical-align:center, but it doesn't like that. What am I doing wrong here?

```css
i.logo {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://www.grampianyoga.org.uk/other/lvo.svg) no-repeat;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  background-size: 200px;
  background-position: 50%
}

.logoheader {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 60px 20px 100px;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.logoheader a {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: black;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class='logoheader'>
    <i class="logo"></i>
    <a href='page.php'>section</a> | <a href='page.php'>contact</a> |
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Show for ex. image how all; of this should look like in result, since image is much bigger than links.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox if your only concern is to center the content vertically.
For eg., take a look at the below attached snippet.

I changed your image to `relative` position and its display to `block` and then inserted them all inside the flexbox.

```css
i.logo {
  position: relative; /*changed this*/
  display: block; /*added this*/
  background: url(http://www.grampianyoga.org.uk/other/lvo.svg) no-repeat;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 200px; /* changed this */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  background-size: 200px;
}

.logoheader {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 60px 20px 100px;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex; /*added this*/
  align-items: center;
}

.logoheader a {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: black;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class='logoheader'>
    <i class="logo"></i>
    <a href='page.php'>section</a> | <a href='page.php'>contact</a> |
  </div>
</nav>
```

Hope it helps!